# Как отдебажить большой sql-запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть большой sql-запрос (почти на 1500 строк), доставшийся по наследству, но не функционирующий правильно.
Нужно отдебажить.
Подскажите, каким образом было бы правильно в нем разобраться?

Сейчас он работает, но возвращает 0 строк.

Comment: выполняйте частями, начиная с самых глубоких слоев вложенности. минимизируйте количество приклеиваемых таблиц. потом добавляете таблицы и смотрите не пропали ли нужные строки

Comment: @Mike, по-ходу, так и придется. Надеялся, что есть какие-нибудь подручные средства для удобства.

Comment: Вы просто приведите сюда блок кода Вашего запроса, тогда решить Ваш вопрос будет легче

Comment: При таких объёмах текста лучше сперва определиться, до конца ли понятна логика того, что этот запрос делает. И подумать, не проще ли тупо взять да написать свою версию от нуля, нежели в чужом [censored] копаться.

Answer (score 0):

с наследством в нашем деле обычно везёт :-)
sql-запрос это в процедурном понимании одна неделимая инструкция, поэтому термин "отладка" не совсем подходит. 
рекомендации такие:

1. упрощение запроса - постарайтесь выделить какие-то очевидные части
   запроса и на основании их создать view, убедиться сначала что view
   работают как нужно, а из запроса в свою очередь обращаться к view -
   это упростит логику и вероятно позволит локализовать проблему
2. анализ плана выполнения запроса - в любом случае полезное занятие,
   так как помимо выявления логических ошибок позволит выявить проблемы
   производительности (например, фильтры без индексов, и т.д.). Это
   команда EXPLAIN <запрос> - выдаст вам протокол всех действий,
   которые выполняет сервер СУБД при выполнении запроса